# Akka gRPC authorization rejection causes "12 INTERNAL" error

Tags: scala, authentication, akka, akka-http, akka-grpc

As mentioned on Akka gRPC documentation (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/akka-http.html) we can interop with Akka Http.

According to sample, request can be rejected (if check fails). But when rejection occures,
always getting "13 INTERNAL" error.
How can we return UNAUTHENTICATED(16) instead of Internal error?

```
val authorizationDirective: Directive0 =
  headerValueByName("token").flatMap { token =>
    if (token == "XYZ") pass
    else reject
  }
```

also throwing exception did not work:

```
val authorizationDirective: Directive0 =
  headerValueByName("token").flatMap { token =>
    if (token == "XYZ") pass
    else throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid Token!")
  }
```

```
01:06:50.972|ERROR|              akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl Error during processing of request: 'Invalid Token!'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
com.xworks.affixzone.api.integration.definition.exception.AuthenticationException: Invalid Token!
```

ps: I tried to use custom ExceptionHandler but it did not work.

Comment: Probably worth looking at [built-in authorize support](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authorize.html) in Akka Http; not sure why the sample doesn't use this.

Comment: Thank you Tim. That is the another way of getting token but at this level (whatever the way get the token is) when token validation is failed, i cant return the GRPC error. It always became HTTP error and than it converted to GRPC 13 INTERNAL  error.

Comment: It's not really a way of getting a token, it is a way of validating credentials and returning the correct HTTP status code. I tried it and got the appropriate error code, but I was using `authenticateBasic` so if it doesn't work for you with tokens then there must be a different problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Not another way of getting token. But it does not solve my problem. Because whatever code raised (except success 200) Akka grpc always returning 13 INTERNAL error